# What are some greatest blunders from the great minds from science?

Tags: physics, discoveries

Einstein said that incorporating the cosmological constant to his equations of general relativity was the greatest blunder of his life. But as it turns out, cosmological constant does indeed have application in understanding the evolution of the universe. So Einstein's greatest blunder indeed became a new way to reveal the secrets of the universe. So it was a mistake, considered by Einstein that revolutionized physics.

So what are some other great blunders from great scientific minds that changed the way of science as we know it?

Comment: Einstein probably never said it was his greatest blunder according to this: http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/08/einstein-likely-never-said-one-of-his-most-oft-quoted-phrases/278508/

Comment: But every biography I read, on his life, everybody mentioned that he said that it was his greatest blunder. I don't know how much truth in that, but I just said what I've read so many times.